# MotionLayout with Viewpager's Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I have a layout as such;

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/motion_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layoutDescription="@xml/motion_layout_details">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back"
    app:title="ToolbarTitle" />

 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="244dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tl_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    app:tabIndicator="@null"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabRippleColor="@null" />

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_menu"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

With identical viewpager items that contain a recyclerview;

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_16dp">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_24dp"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have a motion scene that collapses the image when scrolled up (the configurations for this are correct). If in my viewpager items I wrap my RecyclerView in a nestedscrollview my transition -

```
   <Transition
    app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    app:duration="500"
    app:motionInterpolator="linear">

    <OnSwipe
        app:dragDirection="dragUp"
        app:touchAnchorId="@+id/vp_menu"
        app:touchAnchorSide="top" />

</Transition>
```

Works just fine, and transitions as I'd expect. But removing that nested scrollview no longer triggers the motion layout at all. I've dug around for a good couple of hours and can't seem to find any explanation. I could put the nestedscrollview back in, but ideally I'd like to leave it out as A) it's not needed and B) breaks some stickheader stuff I'm using.

**UPDATE**
Fixed this as per my comment. `.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false` stops the recyclerview communicating with the motionlayout.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, from when I had my recyclerview in a nestedscrollview I had `rv?.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false` which must be stopping some kind of trigger for the motionlayout. Removing this has fixed the issue and works with the above code.